# Whitespace under the cursor in vim

Tags: editor, text-editor, vim

I recently saw this [demo](http://www.flickr.com/photos/30496122@N07/2862367534/sizes/o/). My question is: how is it possible in vim to show whitespace characters under the cursor as dots (in red for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Highlight whitespace before and after the cursor**

```
highlight FooBar guibg=#80a0ff
au CursorMoved * :match FooBar /\s*\%#.\s*/
```

That works for normal mode with gvim. To make it work in terminal vim change the guibg to ctermbg. If you want it also in insert mode, change `au CursorMoved` to

```
au CursorMoved,CursorMovedI,InsertEnter
```

Although in that case you'd need to tweak the regex since that one matches erroneously non-whitespace characters to the right of the cursor when entering insert mode.

In the regex <kbd>\%#</kbd> matches the current cursor position. I had to use <kbd>.</kbd> after it since it wouldn't match whitespace to the right of the cursor without it.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think that's showing space under the cursor; I think it's showing trailing spaces. This is controlled by the `listchars` option, which controls the behavior of `list`. To turn it on, use:

```
set list
set listchars=trail:·
```

The color is determined by the `hl-SpecialKey` group; you can change it like this:

```
hi SpecialKey ctermfg=Red
```

Comment: The intent of `listchars` is to let you distinguish types of whitespace - you can show end of line, tab, trailing whitespace, indicators of more text to left and right of the screen, and nonbreaking spaces. Plain spaces are left blank, because they're common, and with all the other things highlighted, anything blank is a space. The upshot: there's no way to show plain spaces everywhere, and there's certainly no way to apply `list` only "near" the cursor.